# How to disable runtime checks for function templates in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Given the following code:

```
#pragma runtime_checks("u", off)
int f()
{
    int i;
    return i;
} 
#pragma runtime_checks("u", restore)

#pragma runtime_checks("u", off)
template <typename T>
T g()
{
    T i;
    return i;
}
#pragma runtime_checks("u", restore)

#pragma runtime_checks("u", off)
template <>
int g()
{
    int i;
    return i;
}
#pragma runtime_checks("u", restore)

int main()
{
    f();         // Fine
    g<int>();    // Fine
    g<float>();  // Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'i' is being used without being initialized.
    return 0;
}
```

the runtime check disablement will work for the normal function, for the full specialization of the function template but NOT for the generic function template.

How do I disable the runtime checks for the generic function template without disabling them globally in the VS project(I'm using VS2013)?